# Radiative Forcing

Tags: thermal-radiation, sun, climate-science

In a first approximation the radiative forcing $RF$ is related to the temperature change by the linear relation
$$
\Delta T = \lambda \, RF
$$
where
$$
\lambda\approx 0.8 \, \frac{{\rm K}}{{\rm W}/{\rm m^2}}
$$
is the sensitivity parameter which is stated at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_forcing .

Is it possible to derive this relation somehow?
As far as I'm aware the radiative forcing is the effect evoked by additional greenhouse gases (compared to preindustrial times, I think round about 1750) expressed in terms of the same effect which would have been obtained if the solar irradiance would be increased by $RF$.

The basis is the balance of incoming and outgoing flux
$$
\frac{1367 \, \frac{\rm W}{\rm m^2} \cdot 0.7}{4} + RF \approx 240 \, \frac{\rm W}{\rm m^2} + RF  = \epsilon \,\sigma (T+\Delta T)^4 \approx \epsilon \, \sigma \left\{T^4 + 4T^3 \Delta T + {\cal O}\left(\Delta T^2\right) \right\}
$$
where $1367 \, \frac{\rm W}{\rm m^2}$ is the solar constant, the factor $0.7$ on the left accounts for the $30\%$ albedo of the earth and the factor $\frac{1}{4}$ is due to the fact that the incoming total flux is calculated with the effective surface area $\pi R^2$ while it is averaged over the entire sphere with total surface area $4\pi R^2$.

The RHS is the outgoing radiation due to Stefan-Boltzmann. Here $\epsilon$ represents the efficiency of outgoing radiation actually leaving the surface, due to possible absorbers (greenhouse gases) and subsequent diffuse emission. For this value I will assume something like $\epsilon \approx 0.6$ (but maybe somebody knows something better).

This is also how at least I understand the definition of radiative forcing $RF$ i.e. pre-industrially we have $RF=0$ and $\Delta T =0$, giving rise to
$$
T=\left({\frac{240 \, \frac{\rm W}{\rm m^2}}{\epsilon \, \sigma}}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}} \approx 290 \, {\rm K} \, .
$$
Plugging in to first order we have
$$
RF = 3.32 \, \frac{\rm W}{\rm m^2 \, K}\, \Delta T \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad \Delta T = 0.3 \, \frac{\rm K}{\rm W/m^2} \, RF
$$
implying $\lambda \approx 0.3 \, \frac{\rm K}{\rm W/m^2}$.

So my question is: Where does the $0.8$ value come from?
Is this picture of $RF$ correct?

Comment: The answer is no, not usefully.  I think your understanding is correct, but between a simplistic black-body model like this and a realistic calculation there is just an enormous gulf.  To give two examples: you've assumed a value for $\epsilon$: this is something that is computed in a realistic model; you've assumed a value for the abledo and this is *also* something that is computed in (still more) realistic models.  Finally the value of $\lambda$ isn't actually known very well and different models compute different values for it.

Comment: Do you know that range of variation for $\lambda$ different models predict?

Comment: No.  Every time I try to understand this I get confused because what people actually talk about is $\Delta T$ arising from a doubling of CO2, and this seems to me to involve at least two factors: what RF does doubling CO2 correspond to (and from what base value, I presume 1700 or something?), and then what is $\lambda$.  My naive physicist's assumption is that those two parameters are not the same thing in models, but people then talk as if they are and I just get depressed about it and give up.

Comment: The base value is CO2 pre-industrially, or? Wasn't it something like $280 \, {\rm ppm}$ and is now round about $400$ ??
What you are talking about may be methane?

Also the doubling in CO2 affects RF logarithmically, or did you mean something else?

See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13829/why-is-radiative-forcing-from-co2-logarithimic-and-not-a-decreasing-exponential?rq=1

Comment: sorry by '1700' I meant 'value in 1700', ie the usual preindustrial (but recent) value.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were talking about 1700 ppb which would be close to the current methane value. But I think I have heard this number 1750 somewhere floating around.